# java.io.IOException:APN is not specified . what APN i have to set manually to device for Wi-Fi network?

Tags: blackberry, apn

when i searched over the net for this exception , i found it's a comman issue in blackberry http connection's .

as [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/java-io-IOException-APN-is-not-specified-exception-in-Twitter/td-p/1302989) thread says i have to set APN enabled in options >> advanced options >>tcp/ip>>Apn setting enables and write APN here .

i have absolutely no idea from where i can get this APN . does it have anything to do with device model or carrier or internet connection ??? i have blackberry bold with carrier Reliance(india) and wi-fi network .

please guide me how i can find APN ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create connections in blackberry in the following ways

1. BlackBerry® Enterprise Server using the BlackBerry® Mobile Data System (BlackBerry MDS)
2. BlackBerry® Internet Service
3. Direct Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) stack
4. Wi-Fi® network
5. Wireless service provider Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) 1.x gateway
6. Wireless service provider WAP 2.0 gateway

If you use option 3, Direct Transmission Control Protocol you will need to set up APN.

APN is unique for every carrier and every data plan. To get an APN so you can use your app to work on the data network of that carrier, You have to contact them to get the APN settings from them.

APN doesn't depend on the device model. It depends on the carrier and the data plan. A single carrier can have different APN's for different data plans.

Comment: thanks for giving idea about APN .as i mentioned i am using wi-fi for internet instead of carrier . so i am wondering how carrier provider can help in this ??

Comment: To specify that a connection must be made over a Wi-Fi network, the interface=wifi parameter should be used. are you using it.?

Comment: check this as well http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879#4

Comment: my personal experience was : using APN issue will be there till you are using wi-fi , so i used carrier network and now no such issue .